# proof that the series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just need to make sure that I do it correctly

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: OP: How come you managed to accept the only wrong answer? (If ever this question is part of your homework, let me suggest **not** to use the accepted answer as a basis for your hand-out.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the fact $\ln(x) < x$ which makes it easier

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx <  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)|_{x=0}^{1}=\dots. $$

**Note:** Just note that, $ \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2} $ is Riemann integrable (in the extended sense if you wish and $x\sim 0$ $\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\sim \ln(x)$ ) and by the property of the Riemann integral, for $f$ and $g$ Riemann integrable functions such that

$$ f \leq g\quad  \forall x\in[a,b] \implies \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx, $$

then above answer is true

**Another approach:** Note that the integrand has a singularity at $x=0$, so we have

$$ x\sim 0 \implies \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2} \sim \ln(x) $$

and using the fact

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)dx < \infty $$

the original integral converges.

Comment: Since $\ln(x) <0$ on $(0,1)$ and $\ln(0)=-\infty$, this answer is wrong... Otherwise you can prove that any negative improper integral is convergent.

Comment: @Downvoters: I think one down vote will deliver the massage!

Comment: @N.S.: I suggest not to rush to down vote answers.

Comment: @N.S.: It is an answer to a special case and no body is generalizing.

Comment: It is not about comparing values of convergent integrals, but about proving the convergence.

Comment: The first inequality in your post is true but it has nothing to do with the convergence of the integral.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: I am comparing with a convergent integral and I already pointed out the behaving of the integrand near $0$.

Comment: No you aren't, for the exact reason given by N.S.

Comment: @i707107: Off course, we use comparison to prove convergence.

Comment: @Downvoters: The integral is an improper integral but with integrable singularity (as I pointed in the comment) and that's what makes special case here.

Comment: Mhenni, can you explain your reasoning a little more?  Because it seems to me that you're using the existence of $\int_0^1 \ln(x)/(1+x^2)\,dx$ to show that $\int_0^1 \ln(x)/(1+x^2)\,dx < \int_0^1 x/(1+x^2)\,dx$ which you then use to conclude that $\int_0^1 \ln(x)/(1+x^2)\,dx$ exists.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal $\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}$ is NOT Riemann integrable, as it is not bounded.

Comment: @N.S.: I already said in the note "in the extended sense".

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal since your function is negative, you understand that you need to prove that the integral is not NEGATIVE infinity, do you? That is what improper integrable means, which i assume you mean by the "extended" sense....

Comment: @N.S.: Already, it is not $-\infty$. The integrand has an integrable singularity.

Comment: @N.S.: Try to understand Riemann property.

Comment: @serial-downvoter: what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$
\frac{|\log x|}{1+x^2}\leq |\log x|
$$

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful about how you simplify after substituting. $$\frac{e^u}{1+e^{2u}}=\frac{1}{e^{-u}+e^{u}}$$

Note also that $$\int_{-\infty}^0 ue^{-u}du$$ diverges.

I can suggest another route: integrate by parts:

$$\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}dx=\left.\arctan x\log x\right|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx$$

Use that $$\frac{\arctan x}x\to 1$$

so that the integrand is bounded and continuous over $[0,1]$. You'll also have to show that $$\arctan x\log x\to 0 \text{ when } x\to 0$$

You get then that $$\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}dx=-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx=-G$$

where $G$ is [Catalan's constant.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)

Comment: But $\log x \leq 0$ for $x \leq 1$...

Comment: @sos440 Thank you. I think all is correct now.